# How do I give single project access to users in JIRA

Tags: jira

I have been looking for this all over the place for information on this and none of the threads have answered this question as some are really old and others deal with generic project permissions.

I want to give users 1, 2 ability to comment on Jira issues for only one Project i.e. Project X and users 3, 4 ability to comment/report issues on project Y. However, in order to grant login access to JIRA all users seem to be able to browse other projects on my account which is really bad UX.

I have read this documentation: https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver073/managing-project-permissions-861253293.html and it is still dealing with project access for all projects instead of one. How do I cut users from other projects?

Answer (score 0):

With what you explained I understand the biggest problem is all your users has browse permissions. This is something that you need to check if Browse Projects role granted to all users or part of the users. Technically, you can give the browse projects role to all logged in users or just specify specific groups or role for it. I believe this is the best [document](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver073/managing-project-role-membership-861253319.html) to look at for your issue.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. The problem I am having is that if I have a "client" role for a user who can comment on issues etc. but do not have them in Browse Projects, it means they see nothing. When I login as this (client) user I only see a blank dashboard with issues assigned to them but no projects. It seems JIRA can only give you visibility to all projects or none.

Comment: When I grant Browse Projects it then enables them to see everything. It seems JIRA can only give you visibility to all projects or none. How do I prevent the user to see the VIEW ALL PROJECTS dropdown option?

Comment: Have you seen https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-restrict-project-access-to-different-isolated-user-groups-290750862.html ?

Comment: Please note that users will see the browse project but they only able to see those projects that they have access to ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I have created project-X Project-Y users to which assign the browse projects roles depending on which project they are in.